# ggplot giving decimal values in legend while the column has numeric values

Tags: r, ggplot2, decimal, size, legend

[image]

```
plt <- ggplot(data=a,mapping=aes(x=distance, y=rate)) +
    geom_point(aes(size=as.numeric(`Number of years of data`),color=Trend))
```

The column "Number of years of data has values 17 and 18 while the legend shows decimal values.
I was expecting the plot to have only two values i.e 17 and 18
To solve the problem I tried as.numeric which didn't work.

Comment: Compare with and without last line. `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, size = gear)) + geom_point() + scale_size_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1))`. Depending on the range of the data, ggplot2 will sometimes express continuous data with more granularity than you might want.

Comment: @JonSpring Post as answer? I'm not finding a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot2` uses some heuristics to determine useful breaks in a continuous variable. In your case, you know that 17 and 18 are the only values, but ggplot2 is guessing that 17.25 might also be a useful point along the range of data to show. Under the hood, I believe it uses `scales::breaks_extended()` or `scales::breaks_pretty()` to look for a precision that results in 5-ish breaks.

We have a few options if we want to overrule that default. Let's take an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, size = gear)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Here we have three continuous variables. `mpg` has break labels from 10:35, with 6 breaks, each 5 apart. `wt` is shown from 2 to 5, with 4 breaks each 1 apart. `gear` ranges from 3:5 and is shown with 5 breaks each 0.5 apart. We know that a car can't have 3.5 gears, but ggplot2 doesn't know inherently that `gear` can only be integer values -- it assumes all numeric variables could be continuous, even if their type is integer.

One option is to specify the breaks ourselves. We could use something like `breaks = 3:5`, or `breaks = unique(mtcars$gear)`, or specify the distance between breaks with `scales::breaks_width()`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, size = gear)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1))
```

[image]

Another option would be to make the variable into `character` or `factor` data, so that ggplot2 treats it as discrete data with one legend value for each value found in the data. `factor` is usually preferable since it can keep the original ordering; `character` will show "100" as if it were smaller than "90" because it comes earlier in alphabetic order. In either case, you would lose the proportionality that can be achieved when mapping numeric data, where.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, size = as.factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]